# How to implement Build Variants/Flavors in Dart pubspec like in Gradle?

Tags: dart, dart-pub, pubspec

Gradle has a convenient feature to implement separate build variants/flavors. Is there such feature in Dart (**not Flutter**)? I need to implement different codebases (different implementations) for one project, depending on the selected build variant. For example, I could put two different implementations in different (separated) packages and import them depending on the compile-time condition. Dart has conditional imports, but it seems they don't allow custom conditions.